# Why does Mint 17.3 64 Bit search faster than I can type?

Tags: linux, files

When doing a file search (ctrl f) on Cinnamon 64 Bit Mint 17.3 Rosa, I cannot type fast enough because it starts searching for the first letter I type. I have to paste the whole word in to avoid that.

Comment: What do you use to search with ctrl f? The file manager Nemo? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/668521/edit) your question.

Comment: Either while in Documents, Home, or a USB drive folder. I use ctrl f. That works on my 19.x 32 Bit laptop with no autocomplete issues.

Comment: If the answer helped you to resolve the issue, could you please accept it? If you resolved it another way, please don't hesitate to [answer your own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) and accept the answer as well. That marks this as containing solution in searches, and removes it from the Unanswered -queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a feature in Mint 17.3 that's been bugging users for some years now. Here's a couple of threads from Mint forums discussing this, with number of solutions:

- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=211162
- https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=213201

If these don't help, you'll probably find more there.

17.3 is a bit on the old side. Current version is 20.02. It'd be worthwhile to check if the behavior has been changed somewhere in between.

Comment: 19.x works on one of my PC's. Tried 20.x but it did not work well. I will try Catfish as you suggested on first link.

Comment: Just to be clear - I've not suggested any applications, just checking what's in the Mint forums :-) I don't use Mint myself. Please do edit your original question with any testing you do, apps you test etc. instead of answering in comments. That way everything's easily seen by any community member who wants to pitch in.

Comment: I only said the app Catfish, because the first link you sent referenced it.

Comment: Yeah, no worries :-) But please do indeed update the question as news happen.